# Selenium Grid: node with many instances vs instance per node

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Is there any benefit of running many Chrome instances per Chrome node, vs running just one instance per node?

I've always used the second case, I have a Hub and many nodes, each with only one instance. But I just read a tutorial in which the author followed the other approach, and made me wonder what's most efficient.

So, is there any particular reason to use on approach or the other?

Comment: Your code trials ?

Comment: each nodes will be on separate machine right? your question of which method is efficient will then heavily depend on the configuration of the systems.